# R magics not working in IPython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, rpy2, ipython-magic

### Issue with Rmagics in IPython Notebook:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(20)
%R -i A
%R mean(A)
```

returns the the error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'typeof'

when I use **%load_ext rmagic** in place of **%load_ext rpy2.ipython** I get the same error message. Any insight or help would be appreciated.

### Software and System Summary:

- IPython version 2.0.0
- python version 2.7.3
- rpy2 version  3.4.2
- R version 3.3.1
- Ubuntu 12.04.4 Precise Pangolin

Comment: This seems to be an unfixed bug. It is mentioned in this issue: https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/issue/194/libr-not-found-on-os-x-with-homebrew-r, however no one has started a new issue for this bug, yet. If you have the time, it would certainly be a good idea to file an issue at bitbucket.

Comment: See also: https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/issue/218/tests-failed-related-with-numpyndarray-no

Comment: @cel The issue #194 is fixed... although only in 2.5.0-dev.

Comment: This specific error is now addressed in version_2.4.x (but not released yet). Followup for fixing behavior of DataFrame objects continues in [issue 206](https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/issue/206/numpy2ri-pandas2ri-no-longer-properly)